# Can't ask questions on Area51 discussion

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

If I try going to https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask ("ask question"), I get "Oops! Something Bad Happened!".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We experienced a brief outage on a machine responsible for syncing parent/child accounts (in this case, area51 to discuss); if you got unlucky and needed an account sync during this period viewing a page on any meta (including discuss) was likely to error on you.

This appears to have been fixed, but we're keeping a close eye on it just in case.