# Broken Stack Exchange Inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

My inbox displays nothing:

[image]

There was a notification badge telling that I had 2 items to read, so it looks like a bug.

Looking at the XHR tab of the web inspector, I could learn that `/inbox/genuwine` returned `[]` (an empty JSON array, presumably) to my browser, so the issue seems to be somewhere server-side.

Comment: @KevinMontrose I have this same bug that just started ~1 hour ago.  Is there something else that has bugged out?

Comment: I also have this problem. My inbox is empty, even if there are new updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed now.

Related to the server [outage mentioned here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83889/cant-ask-questions-on-area51-discussion/83891#83891).

Comment: A new response just showed up (so that part of the problem is working now), but it doesn't list anything that happened before that. Will earlier entries return?

Comment: This is not fixed for me. Inbox is always blank.