# inbox empty in system-wide stack exchange notification bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, notification-bar

About ~2 hours ago I noticed an alert on my notification bar that there was a response somewhere on the SE network. I clicked on it and the inbox was empty.

It has stayed empty since and I've logged out and back in and logged on in three different browsers.

I found this bug request ([Broken Stack Exchange Inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83890/broken-stack-exchange-inbox)) on meta, but that was closed three days ago, so I'm not sure if this is the same bug or something different.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, not quite sure what went wrong there.

I've bounced your inbox, so it should be displaying correctly now.

Comment: Yes, it is working now.  Thanks!

Comment: I still have this problem.